# Excel - Check if there is a match to a cell in the rest of the workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I've got a workbook that has spread a list across 10 different worksheets, but the list has become out of date. I'm trying to find out which of those in the new list aren't already included in one of the other worksheets.

Basically, I'm looking for a formula that will tell me whether or not the contents of a cell can be matched anywhere else in a workbook.

Cheers.

Comment: Nothing yet, to be honest. I'm not very experienced with excel; my abilities pretty much start and end with vlookup. I would use that but I don't think you can make a table across multiple worksheets.

Comment: What you have to do is copy and paste each list, from each worksheet (all in one long column), into a new worksheet. Then sort the list in alphabetical order so you can see any duplicates. Start from there. It's a manual process. This is the process whereas a formula will not work in this scenario. I would try to keep one list from that point on. Since I've no idea of what those lists are for, I can't further suggest a different approach in a better approach of tracking for future projects.

Comment: @ejbytes if OP did put everything into a single column (which wouldn't be my approach) why wouldn't OP use conditional formatting to highlight duplicates?

Comment: @Raystafarian Why don't you write up a solution? What formula to use from several worksheets. Why are you asking me?

Comment: @ejbytes I'm addressing you because it didn't seem you considered that option, which would be a lot easier than a manual procedure. I thought that information might be useful to you sometime in the future.

Comment: @ejbytes Thanks for the response, but unfortunately that wouldn't work; they need to be in separate lists. Do you know of any other solutions?

Comment: What are you working with? How long are those lists? Are the lists the same width (same number of columns)? Put a screen shot of what you have if it's ideal to get your point across. Do you name your lists with naming properties?

Comment: It's a list of about 2000 URLs that have been categorised based upon their subject matter. Each category has their own page, and each category has a few subcategories. The newer list has about 500 more URL's, but I'm not all that sure which ones are new and which aren't. I could do it the way you've suggested, but that will take a while and then I'd just have to move them all back again.

Comment: I see. If they are indeed in categories, how could there be duplicates? Or why? Do you mean: horror/sci-fi, could also be sci-fy/horror? I'm wondering if a new approach wouldn't be more suitable for your future endeavors. My suggestion would be to get this into one spreadsheet and add a column for "Category". This would have your information in one place. It would be ideal for you to use Access, because it looks like you have a Database project. Otherwise, in Excel, If you had a new column, then you could manipulate the data very easily. There is no quick fix I'm afraid.

Comment: I added a working "answer". This might help you think in terms of "tables" and "database" if you're not familiar with this idea, the image might help you understand how and why it's used. Excel can do this, but in a different way. You'd have to use the sort functionality, or even a "subtotal" with use of "change in 'Genre'"; for example.

Comment: Oh well, I guess I'll just have to do it manually then. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Consider making your "Lists" a database. Think of each list as a category as you have already stated. You would need a column for "category" and/or each "subcategory". Consider the image here. I am a movie buff and created this database for my movies that can be categorized by Genre, and sub-genre, and further by runtime, leading actor, or even actor mentioned in the movie, and release date. Click on the image for a "zoomed view".

[image]

The top is an image of my working database in "Design View". This is a database set up in MS Access. The image below the database is my "Table". Your lists are actually tables. A table is nothing less than a list. Take a closer look at the columns in my "table". With these headings I can manipulate my Titles and a dynamic way and sort them any way I wish. Although this is more than what you are doing with your Excel datasheet lists, I hope this will inspire you to think in terms of data and tables, instead of lists.

Comment: This is only a working answer for sake of images for illustration to help demonstrate why a database with tables is more useful over several lists. The table in the image (bottom portion) gives perspective on how to arrange a list in an excel spreadsheet; needed header values for data manipulation and sorting/filtering (querying).